# ¿Cómo mostrar datos en la vista con vue y Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

estoy tratando de mostrar datos de una bd en la vista que esta con Vue, no se logra ver, no se que me falta o que error tengo, quisiera su ayuda porfavor

```
<div v-for="item in algunaVez">                                                              
     <div><label>{{item.nombre}}</label></div>                                     
</div>
```

Mi controlador:

```
public function perfilCliente($id)
    {        
        $cliente = Cliente::find($id);
        $matricula = Matricula::where('id_cliente', $id)->first();
        $algunaVez = Alguna_vez_matriculado::where('id_matricula', $matricula->id)->first();
        $cliente_id = $cliente->id;
        return view('clientes.perfil')->with(compact('cliente_id','algunaVez','sintomas','otrosAspectos'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

yo haría otro método para traer los datos mediante fetch o axios desde vue.

en el método perfilCliente() que ya tienes solo devolvería la vista y la variable $cliente_id($id)

y la colocaria en un input hidden:

```
<input type="hidden" id="client_id" value="{{$client_id}}">
```

luego en vue capturo esa variable y en el hook created, ejecuto una peticion a otro metodo php que me traiga el resto de datos, y de esta forma ya los tengo en vue.

```
data() {
    return {
        client_id: document.querySelector("#client_id").value,
        items: [];
     }
},
created() {
  axios.get('/get_items/' + this.client_id).then(response => {
     this.items= response.data; //Aqui ya tengo en vue los datos
  }).catch(e => {
     alert("No se pudo cargar los items");
  }); 
}
```

Luego en el controlador php creo otro metodo que va a recibir el $client_id y retornar los datos que requiero.

```
public function getItems($id)
{
    $cliente = Cliente::find($id);
    $algunaVez = Alguna_vez_matriculado::where('id_matricula', $matricula->id)->first();
    return response()->json($algunaVez);
}
```